# C# Visualize Dataset Tables at Runtime?

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, visualization

Looking for code or component that I can use to provide the end user with a visualization of the DataTables in a DataSet at run time.  Using Visual Studio 2017.
I have a dataset that contains a varying number of different datatables and I would like to be able to show the users an overview of the datatables in a dataset - somewhat like what is available in VisualStudio at Design Time.  I am somewhat flexible on how this would look - but I would like to see some indication of what tables are in the dataset at that time.

Any thoughts or known components that might do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, show your efforts. SO is not a free-coding service.

Comment: JohnyL - I am not looking for someone to code this.  What I am asking is if anyone knows of any components that do this.  I have no problem buying them if they exist.  I am not sure why you posted your comment about a free coding service?  I do not see how one would do this without duplicating the dataset designer in Visual Studio - which is why I am curious if others have seen this sort of component.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I now have a solution.  I ended up using Active Query Builder - so I purchased their components for Visual Studio.  This component allows you to build SQL queries visually - but you can also use various stand alone included components to build a very nice graphical view of the DataTables in a DataSet. 
The vendor was very helpful in how I might do this - answering lots of questions - as the components are not setup for this out of the box.
If anyone wants a copy of the code - I will happily provide it!  But you will need a license of Active Query Builder in order to use it.